# amazon aws ip of a private instance whitelisted on a third party

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, whitelist

I have a Node service deployed on a private(inside the private subnet) AWS EC2 Instance. 
I want to call certain third party APIs but the third allows these calls from whitelisted IPs. 
The outbound rule is ALL TRAFFIC. Which IP address should be whitelisted? The private IP itself or the public IP i got when i made a internet bound API call from the machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should whitelist the public IP.

In a [private network topology](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/VPC_Scenario2.html), the "public IP" of your private instances is the one of the NAT Gateway that is located in the public subnet.